# How to use TextField add subview TagView programming by swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, taglist

Sorry I'm beginner.
This is my tagView input Demo(import TagListView).

https://github.com/Bruce9487/TagViewTest

I want to practice tag input. But my constrain looks strange. I don't want tagView to update vertically. And textfield cursor always behind the tagView.How to set constrain of tagView correctly? Thanks.

update: (after I add @hament miglani answer)

[image: tagview under the textview]

Answer (score 0):

There is little mistake, U are not passing frame of the view! Thats why 
this condition in TagListView always true

> if currentRowTagCount == 0 || currentRowWidth + tagView.frame.width >
>   self.frame.width

To solve this you have to pass frame when u are making its object in controller. Showing below:
Add this line of code

> textFieldTagView.frame = textField.frame

in ViewController viewDidload method, just above this line
**textField.addSubview(textFieldTagView)**

Comment: I want to do like this.

Comment: making its library or want to use in your project?